# Is there a equals minus assignment operator (=-)

Tags: java, android

So I know about the assignment operators like `+=`, `-=` and so on, but is there a way to simplify the following code?

```
int varA = 1;
varA = 10 - varA;
```

Thanks in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I think that code is incredibly simple as is, personally.

Comment: A quick perusal of §3.12 of the JLS would have answered that question for you. It's extremely short and easy to assimilate. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12

Comment: "but is there a way to simplify the following code?" `int varA = 9;` (I know, this isn't what you mean...).

Comment: Well if you really want to go with that simplification heres a simplified one `varA = -(varA  += -(10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such operator exists in Java. The way to rewrite such code using combined/DRY operators is:

```
int varA = 1;
varA *= -1;
varA += 10;
```

...which is considerably longer and more confusing than `varA = 10 - varA;`.

Thus, in almost all cases, the way you had it originally is preferable.

Comment: It won't let me for another 3 minutes or so because the question is still too new :P

Comment: No problem; take your time! Good luck with the rest of your project :)